# Ruby on Rails Error: undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, undefined

I've been following along a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-l2XhRyVEo) using Ruby on Rails to build an E-commerce Site but have run into this error:

```
undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
```

It's being drawn from the 3rd line of app/views/pages/home.html.erb:

```
<h1 id="article-title"><%= @product.title %><span class="font-weight-light"><%= @product.subtitle %></span></h1>
```

I am using Ruby 2.3.0, and Rails 5.0.0.

My app/controllers/pages_controller.rb looks like this:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @product  = Product.find_by_sku("bearOne")
  end
end
```

The products are created in db/seeds.rb like this:

```
theBear = Product.create(title: "Bear (on white)",
subtitle: "This Product", image_name: "bribear.jpg",
price: "20.00", sku: "bearOne", download_url: "https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/myproject/bribear.jpg",
details: "These are the details", description: %{<p>Bear On White</p>
})
```

The error pops out as I try to go the home page of the server site. I don't have "private" anywhere, which was the most-frequent problem I had found.

Comment: bear in mind, `find_by` returns `nil` if find nothing.

Comment: Are you sure that the product was created (you ran `rake db:seed`)? Can you retreive the product in rails console?

Comment: I mistakenly wrote app/db/seeds.rb above but it was in db/seeds.rb and I did run 'rake db:seed'. How can I check to retrieve the product in the console?

Answer (score 0):

I think you placed your seeding file in the wrong folder, it should be in ***your_rails_project_folder/db/seeds.rb***.

Once you have it in the right place, run ***'rake db:seed'***, then when you navigate to the app it should work.

Comment: I mistakenly wrote app/db/seeds.rb above but it was in db/seeds.rb and I did run 'rake db:seed'

Comment: try replacing create with create!, it will throw the cause of error in your db/seeds.rb file.

Answer (score 0):

Place code in correct folder:

## db/seeds.rb

```
theBear = Product.create!(title: "Bear (on white)",
subtitle: "This Product", image_name: "bribear.jpg",
price: "20.00", sku: "bearOne", download_url: "https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/myproject/bribear.jpg",
details: "These are the details", description: %{<p>Bear On White</p>
})
```

Run Command:  `rake db:seed` to run seed file and create product.

## app/controllers/pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @product  = Product.find_by_sku("bearOne")
  end
end
```

## app/views/pages/home.html.erb:

```
<h1 id="article-title"><%= @product.try(:title) %><span class="font-weight-light"><%= @product.subtitle %></span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized there was an inconsistency between the fields of the products being created and the schema.rb file. I fixed the missing attribute and 'ran rake db:reset', which fixed my problem.